# How to get file(s) from an HTML file input and send it as an attachment to an email in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

This HTML code takes file inputs using Google Script's class HTML service :

(SEE BELOW)

I would like to get the value(s)(the files) of the input field, send to the my .gs file and send that as an attachment to the email.

Getting the value from the input field simply returns the directory of the file, which is no help because Google Apps Script can't obtain files from local drive.

I have done a lengthy research with this problem and I can't find anyone with a similar issue.

Stack Code.gs

```
function myFunction() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stack HTML').setWidth(250).setHeight(250);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,'Get File');
}

function processEmail(files){
  
  var subject = 'Subject';
  var message = 'Test';
  var recipient = 'test@gmail.com';
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message, {attachments: files, htmlBody: message, name:'Stack Overflow Test'});  // Doesn't work

  
}
```

Stack HTML.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div>
     <input type="file" id= "file" multiple = "true">
     </div>
     </form>
     <br><div style="text-align:center"> <input type="submit" name = "submitButton" onclick = "send()" id = "sendButton" value="Send"></div>
     
   <script>
   
   function done(e){
       google.script.host.close();
   }
   
   
   function send(){
      var files = document.getElementById("file").value;
      console.log(files);
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(done).processEmail(files);
   }
   
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide your whole script including HTML, Javascript side and Google Apps Script side? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: No problem Tanaike! I have updated my code. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. In your script, `multiple` is used for input tag. So should we think that you want to upload multiple files?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) ?

Comment: Yes Tanaike, I would like it to take 1 or more files. TheMaster, I will go and look into the link, thank you.

Comment: @Mahmoud Maarouf Thank you for replying. I noticed your replying earlier. I apologize this. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @TheMaster I tried to [the script of the link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) for the multiple files. The 1st file can be retrieved. But I couldn't retrieve all files. I think that if that method can be used, the script becomes more simple. Unfortunately, I cannot still find the method for the multiple files.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes. Can confirm. Tested a bunch of other methods too.  Your answer is the shortest and easiest.

Comment: Than you Tanaike and @TheMaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to upload multiple files from local PC to Google Drive using HTML and Javascript.
- You want to send the uploaded files as the attachment files of an email.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Solution:

From your question, the files are used as the attachment files of an email. So I thought that the following flow can be used for your situation.

1. Retrieve all files from the local PC.
2. All files are summarized as an object.

   - At this time, the files are converted to the base64 string value.
3. Send the object to Google side.
4. Convert the object to file blob at GAS side.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `send()` in HTML side as follows.

```
function send() {
  const f = document.getElementById('file');
  Promise.all([...f.files].map((file, i) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    return new Promise(r => {
      fr.onload = e => {
        const data = e.target.result.split(",");
        r({fileName: file.name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]});
      }
      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }))
  .then(obj => {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(done).processEmail(obj);
  });
}
```

And please modify `processEmail()` in GAS side as follows.

```
function processEmail(obj){
  var files = obj.map(function(e) {return Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(e.data), e.mimeType, e.fileName)});
  var subject = 'Subject';
  var message = 'Test';
  var recipient = 'test@gmail.com';
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message, {attachments: files, htmlBody: message, name:'Stack Overflow Test'});
}
```

#### References:

- [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)
- [Class Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities)
- [Uploading Multiple Files From Local To Google Drive using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88fcae255abb4aac5bec81ad5ca213ef)

Comment: This solution is phenomenal and does not upload anything to my google drive. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way to save the variable obj to a variable so that I may add it to an array? I would like to execute .then before proceeding to the GAS side. Thanks!

Comment: Putting everything inside the .then callback worked. It isn't the prettiest code, but it worked.

Comment: @Mahmoud Maarouf Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.